# detect process name/pid file using the service

Tags: linux, service, redhat, rhel, systemd

I am trying to detect a service PID file or process name, but can not find any usefull commands. The init system can be SYSTEMD or INITV

Does it possible?

thanks

Comment: ps -aux | grep servicename(without . service)  ? Like for nginx.service I use ps -aux | grep nginx

Comment: Did you check the documentation for systemd and SysVInit? Are you trying to detect for /any/ process, or is there is a specific one you want to look up?